# in_array is not working, it appears it should be

Tags: php

Alright, i've tried everything. SO is my last resort!!

heres my code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++){
    $coach = $trainergross[$i]['instr'];
    $tclub = $trainergross[$i]['club'];
    $rookcheck = "$coach $tclub";
    if(in_array(trim(strtolower($rookcheck)), $rook)){
    $pls = 'y no work';
    }
    echo "$rookcheck $pls <br>";
}
```

here is `print_r($rook)`:

`Array ( [0] => jess p )`

and here is what `echo "$rookcheck $pls <br>";` is creating

```
naps d
sarah c
richie e
lee b
kate e
jess p <---- WHY ISNT THIS ECHOING $PLS???
josh d
chris e
```

if i use `in_array('jess p', $rook)` it works. so is the loop breaking this? i dont know. i'm getting mad!

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Try without the `trim`

Comment: try a `print (trim(strtolower($rookcheck)) === "jess p")`. If that says fails, your "jess p" string might not actually the string you think it is. Your actual $rook array content might not be trimmed, or have other subtle differences.

Comment: Just `var_dump()` all your variables and you'll see exactly why it does not work.

Comment: @markbaker i have. no beans. i just added the trim as my last attempt

Comment: I'm with @MarkBaker. It's probably a whitespace issue.

Comment: Have you tried `if(in_array(trim(strtolower($rookcheck)), trim(strtolower($rook))){`?

Comment: @TecBrat String functions are not going to work on an array.

Comment: @jeroen Sorry, got in too much of a hurry. You're absolutely right.

Comment: alright `trim(strtolower($rookcheck)) === "jess p"` also doesn't work.  what does that mean then

Comment: try `echo '*'.$rook[5].'*'` and see what prints.

Comment: And whoever downvoted this, care to explain how this doesn't belong on stackoverflow? Thanks!

Comment: Well there's your problem right there.(you changed your comment after I wrote this.)

Comment: @TecBrat yeah i'm editing out last names and stuff on here sorry haha

Comment: @robz228 A simple `var_dump()` of the variables will show you why the two strings don't match so as far as I am concerned this question does not show any research effort. Also, editing the values of your `echo` and `print_r` before you post them here, makes it impossible for anybody to help you.

Comment: @jeroen var_dump was the first thing i did. here they are `string(6) "JESS P"` & `string(6) "jess p"`. this is why i added strtolower. and its still not working. since i clearly have put such little effort into this maybe you can guide me further?

Comment: @robz228 Not really, `var_dump(strtolower("JESS P") === "jess p");` returns `true` always, with or without an additional `trim` so these are apparently not your real values.

Comment: Is it a space between `jess` and `p` or some other whitespace character such as a tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
$trainergross = array(
        array(
                'instr' => 'naps',
                'club' => 'd',
        ),
        array(
                'instr' => 'sarah',
                'club' => 'c',
        ),
        array(
                'instr' => 'richie',
                'club' => 'e',
        ),
        array(
                'instr' => 'lee',
                'club' => 'b',
        ),
        array(
                'instr' => 'kate',
                'club' => 'e',
        ),
        array(
                'instr' => 'jess',
                'club' => 'p',
        ),
        array(
                'instr' => 'josh',
                'club' => 'd',
        ),
        array(
                'instr' => 'chris',
                'club' => 'e',
        ),
);
$rook[] = "chris e";

for($i = 0; $i < count($trainergross); $i++){
    $coach = $trainergross[$i]['instr'];
    $tclub = $trainergross[$i]['club'];
    $rookcheck = $coach.' '.$tclub;

    if(in_array(trim(strtolower($rookcheck)), $rook)){
        $pls = 'y no work';
    }
    echo $rookcheck.$pls."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to 'reverse engineer' your `$trainergross` array & I think it looks something like this:

```
array(
  array(
    'instr' => 'naps',
    'club' => 'd',
  ), 
  array(
    'instr' => 'sarah',
    'club' => 'c',
  ),
  array(
    'instr' => 'richie',
    'club' => 'e',
  ),
  array(
    'instr' => 'lee',
    'club' => 'b',
  ),
  array(
    'instr' => 'kate',
    'club' => 'e',
  ),
  array(
    'instr' => 'jess',
    'club' => 'p',
  ),
  array(
    'instr' => 'josh',
    'club' => 'd',
  ),
  array(
    'instr' => 'chris',
    'club' => 'e',
  ),
);
```

With this array, your code mostly works. As Wayne Whitty suggested, please use the extra line to set & reset `$pls` in the loop.
Also, because your array doesn't have 15 items, this 15 × for loop will cause errors. You might want to look at the [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) construct.

Comment: I have it at 15 because its displaying a 'top 15' after sorting the array a certain way. and yes, this is what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be most beneficial to present a debugging technique rather than provide the actual answer:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++){
    $coach = $trainergross[$i]['instr'];
    $tclub = $trainergross[$i]['club'];
    $rookcheck = "$coach $tclub";

    // echo your actual IF statement and see if it makes sense
    echo "if(in_array(".trim(strtolower($rookcheck)).", ".print_r($rook, true).")){";

    if(in_array(trim(strtolower($rookcheck)), $rook)){

        // echo something for the heck of it
        echo 'We\'re in!<br>';

        $pls = 'y no work';
    }

    echo "$rookcheck $pls <br>";
}
```